# Should I `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` before actually `UPDATE` in general?

Tags: sql

**In a transaction**, Should I `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the record before actually `UPDATE` it in general?

Or I just `UPDATE` the record? Is there any potential concurrency problem with this?

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE is for WHERE CURRENT OF cursor operations. If you know what row to update simply do UPDATE.

Comment: It depends; `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE NOWAIT` is for *pessemistic lock*: don't touch (`update`, `delete`) my records for a while! Just `Update` is optimistic: just update (but someone else can update these records as well and you can have inconsitent records)

Comment: @jarlh: select for update is not limited to cursor operations

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, when/why specify FOR UPDATE for a non-cursor operation?

Comment: @jarlh: as I wrote in my answer: typically if you want to lock a row (but not update it) manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the `UPDATE` **immediately** after the locking the row (using `select ... for update`) there is no real sense in doing that.

Using `select ... for update` usually only makes sense if you intend to hold that lock while doing other things until you either really update the row or if you don't actually want to update that row.

Comment: For example, thread **A** `SELECT` a record and do something with it and `UPDATE` it and not commit yet. And in the meantime, thread **B** wants to do the same thing with the same record. Does thread **B** `SELECT` it successfully? Does thread **B** `UPDATE` it successfully? Does thread **B** `COMMIT` it successfully?

Comment: And if thread **A** only `SELECT` successfully, and not `UPDATE` it yet. Does thread **B** `SELECT` it successfully? Does thread **B** `UPDATE` it successfully? Does thread **B** `COMMIT` it successfully?

Comment: If the behavior is inconsistent in different databases, can you give some examples of which databases are doing this and which databases are doing that?